# How to find all links that contain 2 or 3 words in tag using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm extracting iframe from website using Beautifulsoup 
    iframes = soup.find_all('iframe')
i want to find all the src tag in that iframes that contain 2 or 3 words 
let's say that i have the src link look like this `"https://xyz.co/embed/TNagkx3oHj8/The.Tale.S001.true.72p.x264-QuebecRules"`
 i know how to extract the links that's containe the word "xyz"

```
srcs = []
 iframes = soup.find_all('iframe')
            for iframe in iframes:
                try:
                    if iframe['src'].find('xyz')>=0: srcs.append(iframe['src'])                 
                except KeyError: continue
```

my question is how to extract all the links that contain 2 words like "xyz" 
and "true" or 3 words 
it's like filter if this 2 words don't exist in that link don't scrap it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to check whether the `src` contains all the words you want.

For example, you can use something like this:

```
soup.find_all('iframe', src=lambda s: all(word in s for word in ('xyz', 'true')))
```

**Demo:**

```
html = '''
    <iframe src="https://xyz.co/embed/TNagkx3oHj8/The.Tale.S001.true.72p.x264-QuebecRules">...</iframe>
    <iframe src="foo">...</iframe>
    <iframe src="xyz">...</iframe>
    <iframe src="xyz.true">...</iframe>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
iframes = soup.find_all('iframe', src=lambda s: all(word in s for word in ('xyz', 'true')))
print(iframes)
```

**Output:**

```
[<iframe src="https://xyz.co/embed/TNagkx3oHj8/The.Tale.S001.true.72p.x264-QuebecRules">...</iframe>, <iframe src="xyz.true">...</iframe>]
```

**Note:**

If any of the `<iframe>` tags does not contain a `src` attribute, the above function will raise an error. In that case, change the function to:

```
soup.find_all('iframe', src=lambda s: s and all(word in s for word in ('xyz', 'true')))
```